# Remembering last Displayed Banner

Tags: php, html, random, setcookie

I am trying to display random banner each time the user refresh the page. The problem I am facing is that I don't want the last banner to be displayed again. I there any other way to remember the last displayed one without using cookies or database implementation?

Cookie Implementation:

```
<?php

$randIndex = rand(1,6);
if(!isset($_COOKIE["lastDispalyed"])){
    setcookie("lastDispalyed",$randIndex,time()+60*60*24);
}
else{       
    while($_COOKIE["lastDispalyed"] == $randIndex){
        $randIndex = rand(1,6);
    } 
    setcookie("lastDispalyed",$randIndex,time()+60*60*24);
} ?>
```

`<img src="images/mainBanners/<?php echo $randIndex; ?>.JPG"/>`

Comment: You could use `$_SESSIONS`. Why don't you want to let them see another ad, also if you only have six you may run out of ads fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could use a session variable:**

```
<?php

    session_start(); // <-- start session before outputting any HTML

    $randIndex = rand(1,6);

    if (!isset($_SESSION["lastDisplayed"])) {

        $_SESSION["lastDisplayed"] = $randIndex;

    } else {    

        while ($_SESSION["lastDisplayed"] == $randIndex) {
            $randIndex = rand(1,6);
        }

        $_SESSION["lastDisplayed"] = $randIndex;
    }

?>
```

Reference [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Comment: @DarrylHebbes What does it say?

Comment: It's displays a timeout message, actually the error mine. 
if rand(1,1) occurs then the while loop spins out.
So no worries, your example is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a session variable for the id or url of the banner:

```
$_SESSION['lastDisplayed'] = $id; //could be the id of the banner you are displaying, or the file's url, whatever you have access too
```

And then test for it when you go to display a new banner.